# Gaussian Plot of event counts vs numerical series

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot data from a spectrometer, and fit a nice gaussian curve to it.

You can see from my code that the graph plots the 'Channel Number' on the x-axis, and on the y-axis, the number of counts for that channel.

Now, here's where I get a bit stuck/confused.

Starting with an example I found on the web, I try to plot the same data but fitted to a normal distribution. It seems to be a list of probability values, rather than count values.

It also looks like the x and y values are reversed. For example, channel 3898 has 590 counts, but you can see that 590 is plotted in the x direction (in cyan).

How can I plot a list of counts, against a series of channel numbers, and have it nicely gaussian shaped?

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths, gaussian
from scipy.stats import norm
import os


spectrum = ['7', '8', '3', '4', '6', '5', '5', '6', '6', '8', '5', '7', '3', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '6', '10', '9', '48', '83', '169', '330', '468', '543', '590', '510', '376', '268', '126', '65', '21', '14', '13', '8', '3', '3', '2', '4', '3', '6', '5', '6', '5', '2', '3', '6', '2', '6', '7', '4', '1', '5']

numericSpectrum = []            #a list to store the spectrum numbers as ints

channelsPerKEV = 3.03           # 8192 channels, 2700KEV full scale, therefore 3.03 channels per kev


print("\n")
print(spectrum)

for stringNumber in spectrum:
    numericSpectrum.append(int(stringNumber))                   #convert the strings to numbers for plotting etc

print("Max Value: "+ str( max(numericSpectrum) ) )

maxChannel = numericSpectrum.index(max(numericSpectrum)) + 3871 #calculate the maximum, then add the starting offset

print("Occurs at Channel: " + str(maxChannel) )
print("\n")

x_range = (3871, 3926)

y = np.array(spectrum, dtype=np.float32)                          #convert the spectrum values to a numpy array of floats

print (y)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(y,height=20)
results_half = peak_widths(y, peaks, rel_height = 0.5)

print("FWHM: " , (results_half[0][0]/channelsPerKEV))
print("\n")

y_position, xmin, xmax = results_half[1:]                        #calculate the height of the halfway line, and the left and right points

print(y_position, xmin, xmax)

plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))

plt.plot(list(range(3871, 3926)), y)

plt.hlines(y_position, xmin=x_range[0]+xmin, xmax=x_range[0]+xmax, color='red')
plt.xlim(x_range)
plt.show()

#-----------below here was modified from an example found online----------------------

# Distribution fitting
# norm.fit(data) returns a list of two parameters 
# (mean,and std, via a MLE approach 
# to data, which should be in array form.
mean, std = norm.fit(numericSpectrum)

print (mean)
print (std)

mean = maxChannel

x = np.linspace(3871,3926,55)

# Generate the pdf (fitted distribution)
fitted_pdf = norm.pdf(x,loc = mean,scale = std)
# Generate the pdf (normal distribution non fitted)
normal_pdf = norm.pdf(x)

print (fitted_pdf)
print (normal_pdf)


plt.plot(x,fitted_pdf,"red",label="Fitted normal dist",linestyle="dashed", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,normal_pdf,"blue",label="Normal dist", linewidth=2)
#plt.hist(numericSpectrum,bins = range(3871, 3926),density=0,color="cyan",alpha=.3) #alpha, from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque)

plt.hist(numericSpectrum,density=0,color="cyan",alpha=.3) #alpha, from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque)

plt.title("Normal distribution fitting")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Pete, welcome to Stack Overflow! We don't include formalities in questions on this site  to make sure users can read and answer as quickly and effectively as possible, so I have edited your question.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! A note on "It seems to be a list of probability values", you're displaying the pdf of the fitted normal distribution, the probability density function, which is indeed a list of probabilities